# Make PowerPoint audio soundtrack work like Keynote

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

In Keynote the audio soundtrack for a whole slideshow can be set to loop, and if the slideshow itself loops, it continues along fine as I would like it to. The audio is just music and doesn't have to match slide contents.

Office 2003 have tried setting an audio file at modify slide transitions to loop until next sound. also... Under custom animation timing, and tried inserting a file to play automatically, set the the effect options to play for 999.

Basically tried every change I could find to try to get the sound to just play a continuous loop without restarting on the first slide. Which is my problem. Restarting audio is not the same behavior as looping in Keynote.

I must be missing something simple, and have to make this work for user editors that do not have macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Go here for looping sound in a single slide
>     http://www.juliatexas.com/powerpoint/powerpointsound.htm
> - **Go here to loop sound throughout the presentation**
>     http://www.presentationmagazine.com/powerpoint_music.htm

Comment: I have tried both of these, in fact they describe what i have tried, very well. Still the audio restarts when the slideshow loop returns to the first slide. Is there a way to either fade the sound out at the last slide, or just be continuous rather than restarting the audio?

Comment: Let me check if this function is available in office 2010

Comment: I can't get this to work on 2010 but it is the answer in other versions, it appears